Clarification on Kernel Version Choices for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hello Ubuntu community,
I've been looking into the kernel version for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and found some conflicting information that has left me a bit confused. According to kernel.org, version 6.6.32 is listed as the latest LTS release. However, the official Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO comes with kernel version 6.8.0 installed, and the latest Stable release is currently listed on kernel.org as version 6.8.11.
This raises a couple of questions:

Is the LTS designation for a kernel version always the one directly
before the latest stable release, or is it specifically the one marked as
LTS on kernel.org? For instance, while 6.6.32 is explicitly labeled
as LTS, the progression to 6.8.0 and beyond suggests a possible
shift.

How does Ubuntu decide which kernel version to use for its LTS
releases? Specifically, why might Ubuntu choose a newer, possibly
non-LTS version like 6.8.0 over one that is marked as LTS on
kernel.org?


The kernel subreddit community seems to regard 6.6.32 as the latest LTS release, which adds an interesting layer to this quandary. I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations regarding how these decisions are made, especially in terms of stability and support implications for Ubuntu LTS releases.
Thank you for helping shed light on this matter!

No one here can answer that as no one here works for the company. That is a question only the developers can answer.

Is the LTS designation for a kernel version always the one directly before the latest stable release, or is it specifically the one marked as LTS on kernel.org?
Neither.
The kernel.org "LTS" designation is not related to the Ubuntu "LTS" designation.
kernel.org explains it this way:

Distribution kernels
Many Linux distributions provide their own "longterm maintenance" kernels that may or may not be based on those maintained by kernel developers.

When the two LTS happen to overlap, that's smart engineering (and perhaps a bit of luck) by the Ubuntu Kernel Team. Overlap is not guaranteed nor required. Many Ubuntu LTS releases have not had such overlap.

How does Ubuntu decide which kernel version to use for its LTS releases?
The same way it decides on the kernel for non-LTS releases.
The Ubuntu Kernel Team reviews the kernels likely to be available around the future release date, balances its workload and resources, and decides upon a LTS GA kernel target.
LTS HWE kernels use most recent 6-month release of Ubuntu.
